# Ionic - Back button close keyboard but input still focused

Tags: javascript, android, html, keyboard, ionic-framework

This causes for very awkward behaviour. When you reselect another input field the keyboard pops up again, but the input field stays behind the keyboard.

When closing the keyboard without using the back button everything works as intended.

This didn't use to be a problem, but after I created a new project using the newest version (v1.0.0 "uranium-unicorn") of ionic this bug occurred.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show some code? you have try so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fixed the problem, I was missing the following plugin:

> cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard

(I suddenly had the realisation after I posted the question)

Comment: I have the similar issue with you, but your solution is not worked for me. I also had the ionic keyboard plugin. And in Android device when input focused ,I tap back button , the keyboard is hidden, but input still focused on.